# In IndexedDB, what is the difference between IDBObjectStore.put and IDBCursor.update?

Tags: javascript, performance, indexeddb

In IndexedDB, there are two ways to update an object already in the database. You can call `IDBCursor.update` or `IDBObjectStore.put`.

Both accept the updated object as a parameter.

`IDBCursor.update` requires you to open a cursor first, but you basically have to do that with `IDBObjectStore.put` too to retrieve the prior value.

`IDBObjectStore.put` will create a new object if it can't find one to update, but since it has to check for an update first, I don't know if this would actually create a performance difference.

So what is the difference between these methods? Is there anything I'm missing? I tried to make a test case to investigate performance differences:

```
var db;

function runTest(N, cb) {
  console.log("N = " + N);

  // Add some fake data to object store
  var tx = db.transaction("store", "readwrite");
  tx.objectStore("store").clear();
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    tx.objectStore("store").add({"id": i, "index":0,"guid":"21310c91-ff31-4cb9-ae68-16d48cbbd84a","isActive":false,"balance":"$1,840.25","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":33,"eyeColor":"brown","name":"Witt Fletcher","gender":"male","company":"QUILM","email":"wittfletcher@quilm.com","phone":"+1 (851) 485-2174","address":"729 Conover Street, Marenisco, Virginia, 7219","about":"Incididunt do deserunt ut quis. Exercitation et ut ad aliqua ut do sint Lorem. Aliquip sit aliquip nulla excepteur pariatur ut laborum ea dolor. Consectetur incididunt et et esse commodo id eu dolor in. Nostrud sit mollit occaecat ullamco commodo aute anim duis enim et aliqua. Aute duis nostrud do minim labore sunt mollit in voluptate aliquip sit. Aliqua aliquip non ipsum exercitation cillum irure in.\r\n","registered":"2014-07-02T03:42:57 +04:00","latitude":-65.942119,"longitude":-129.471674,"tags":["reprehenderit","nostrud","velit","exercitation","nulla","nulla","est"],"friends":[{"id":0,"name":"Kristine Francis"},{"id":1,"name":"Lizzie Ruiz"},{"id":2,"name":"Bobbie Underwood"}],"greeting":"Hello, Witt Fletcher! You have 7 unread messages.","favoriteFruit":"apple"});
  }
  tx.oncomplete = function () {
    // Update with cursor.update
    var tStart = (new Date()).getTime();
    tx = db.transaction("store", "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("store");
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      store.openCursor(i).onsuccess = function (event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        cursor.value.age = 34;
        cursor.update(cursor.value);
      };
    }
    tx.oncomplete = function () {
      var tEnd = (new Date()).getTime();
      console.log("cursor.update - " + (tEnd - tStart) + " milliseconds");

      // Update with put
      tStart = (new Date()).getTime();
      tx = db.transaction("store", "readwrite");
      store = tx.objectStore("store");
      for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        store.openCursor(i).onsuccess = function (event) {
          var cursor = event.target.result;
          cursor.value.age = 34;
          store.put(cursor.value);
        };
      }
      tx.oncomplete = function () {
        tEnd = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log("put - " + (tEnd - tStart) + " milliseconds");

        if (cb !== undefined) {
          cb();
        }
      };
    };
  };
}

request = indexedDB.open("yes5ytrye", 1);
request.onerror = function (event) { console.log(event); };

request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  db.onerror = function (event) { console.log(event); };

  db.createObjectStore("store", {keyPath: "id"});
};

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
  db = request.result;
  db.onerror = function (event) { console.log(event); };

  runTest(100, function () {
    runTest(1000, function () {
      runTest(10000, function () {
        console.log("Done");
      });
    });
  });
};
```

You can try it [here](http://play.basketball-gm.com/test_case).

In Firefox, I get output like:

```
N = 100
cursor.update - 39 milliseconds
put - 40 milliseconds
N = 1000
cursor.update - 229 milliseconds
put - 256 milliseconds
N = 10000
cursor.update - 2194 milliseconds
put - 2096 milliseconds
Done
```

Basically no difference in performance. The results are a little different in Chrome when `N` is large:

```
N = 100
cursor.update - 51 milliseconds
put - 44 milliseconds
N = 1000
cursor.update - 414 milliseconds
put - 447 milliseconds
N = 10000
cursor.update - 13506 milliseconds
put - 22783 milliseconds
Done
```

But like I said above, I'm not even sure if there should be a difference between these two methods, because it seems like they have to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between `update cursor` and `put`, is the fact that you need to retrieve the element you want to update with `cursor`; on the other hand when using the `put` statement, you only need to know the `id` of the element you are updating and you just execute the `put` function which is defined on the `store` level. However this speed up will only work in cases where you have the complete object stored in memory.

I updated your code a bit and got the speed up:

```js
var db;

function runTest(N, cb) {
  console.log("N = " + N);

  // Add some fake data to object store
  var tx = db.transaction("store", "readwrite");
  tx.objectStore("store").clear();
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    tx.objectStore("store").add({"id": i, "index":0,"guid":"21310c91-ff31-4cb9-ae68-16d48cbbd84a","isActive":false,"balance":"$1,840.25","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":33,"eyeColor":"brown","name":"Witt Fletcher","gender":"male","company":"QUILM","email":"wittfletcher@quilm.com","phone":"+1 (851) 485-2174","address":"729 Conover Street, Marenisco, Virginia, 7219","about":"Incididunt do deserunt ut quis. Exercitation et ut ad aliqua ut do sint Lorem. Aliquip sit aliquip nulla excepteur pariatur ut laborum ea dolor. Consectetur incididunt et et esse commodo id eu dolor in. Nostrud sit mollit occaecat ullamco commodo aute anim duis enim et aliqua. Aute duis nostrud do minim labore sunt mollit in voluptate aliquip sit. Aliqua aliquip non ipsum exercitation cillum irure in.\r\n","registered":"2014-07-02T03:42:57 +04:00","latitude":-65.942119,"longitude":-129.471674,"tags":["reprehenderit","nostrud","velit","exercitation","nulla","nulla","est"],"friends":[{"id":0,"name":"Kristine Francis"},{"id":1,"name":"Lizzie Ruiz"},{"id":2,"name":"Bobbie Underwood"}],"greeting":"Hello, Witt Fletcher! You have 7 unread messages.","favoriteFruit":"apple"});
  }
  tx.oncomplete = function () {
    // Update with cursor.update
    var tStart = (new Date()).getTime();
    tx = db.transaction("store", "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("store");
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      store.openCursor(i).onsuccess = function (event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        cursor.value.age = 34;
        cursor.update(cursor.value);
      };
    }
    tx.oncomplete = function () {
      var tEnd = (new Date()).getTime();
      console.log("cursor.update - " + (tEnd - tStart) + " milliseconds");

      // Update with put
      tStart = (new Date()).getTime();
      tx = db.transaction("store", "readwrite");
      store = tx.objectStore("store");
      for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          //you don't need the element just update
        store.put({"id": i, "index":0,"guid":"21310c91-ff31-4cb9-ae68-16d48cbbd84a","isActive":false,"balance":"$1,840.25","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":33,"eyeColor":"brown","name":"Witt Fletcher","gender":"male","company":"QUILM","email":"wittfletcher@quilm.com","phone":"+1 (851) 485-2174","address":"729 Conover Street, Marenisco, Virginia, 7219","about":"Incididunt do deserunt ut quis. Exercitation et ut ad aliqua ut do sint Lorem. Aliquip sit aliquip nulla excepteur pariatur ut laborum ea dolor. Consectetur incididunt et et esse commodo id eu dolor in. Nostrud sit mollit occaecat ullamco commodo aute anim duis enim et aliqua. Aute duis nostrud do minim labore sunt mollit in voluptate aliquip sit. Aliqua aliquip non ipsum exercitation cillum irure in.\r\n","registered":"2014-07-02T03:42:57 +04:00","latitude":-65.942119,"longitude":-129.471674,"tags":["reprehenderit","nostrud","velit","exercitation","nulla","nulla","est"],"friends":[{"id":0,"name":"Kristine Francis"},{"id":1,"name":"Lizzie Ruiz"},{"id":2,"name":"Bobbie Underwood"}],"greeting":"Hello, Witt Fletcher! You have 7 unread messages.","favoriteFruit":"apple"});
      }
      tx.oncomplete = function () {
        tEnd = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log("put - " + (tEnd - tStart) + " milliseconds");

        if (cb !== undefined) {
          cb();
        }
      };
    };
  };
}

request = indexedDB.open("yes5ytrye", 1);
request.onerror = function (event) { console.log(event); };

request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  db.onerror = function (event) { console.log(event); };

  db.createObjectStore("store", {keyPath: "id"});
};

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
  db = request.result;
  db.onerror = function (event) { console.log(event); };

  runTest(100, function () {
    runTest(1000, function () {
      runTest(10000, function () {
        console.log("Done");
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Here are my results:

```
N = 100
cursor.update - 46 milliseconds
put - 28 milliseconds
N = 1000
cursor.update - 157 milliseconds
put - 114 milliseconds
N = 10000
cursor.update - 5530 milliseconds
put - 2391 milliseconds
Done
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are same in the sense that both of them use to update a record value. Use simple `put` if you already know the key and value,  otherewise a bit convoluted cursor update is only option.

Performance should be same for updating a record.